# How to find the position of key value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with user id and transaction details sorted based on transaction. Now I need to find the position of key value

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 3
            [transaction] => 1878
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 2
            [transaction] => 416
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 5
            [transaction] => 353
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 4
            [transaction] => 183
        )
)
```

When I give user id 4 then it should return 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to fetch all `userid`, then use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to retrieve array key.

```
$searchId = 4;
echo array_search( $searchId, array_column($array, 'userid') ) );
```

Comment: use echo array_search(  $searchId, array_column($array, 'userid') );

Answer (score 1):

I might just iterate the outer array here and the check the key values:

```
$pos = -1;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i]['userid'] == 4) {
        $pos = $i;
    }
}

if ($pos == -1) {
    echo "user not found";
}
else {
    echo "user found at position " . $pos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro I didn't think this way.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Calos's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919641/how-to-find-the-position-of-key-value-in-an-array#answer-53919709) answer.

The code below imitates JavaScript's [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to achieve what you need. Using this approach you can have more flexibility in searching the array by using a callback function, similar to how JavaScript has done it.

You can also easily reuse it in other parts of your code.

```
$data = [
    [
        'userid' => 3,
        'transaction' => 1878
    ],
    [
        'userid' => 2,
        'transaction' => 416
    ],
    [
        'userid' => 5,
        'transaction' => 353
    ],
    [
        'userid' => 4,
        'transaction' => 183
    ]
];

function findIndex($array, $method){
    foreach($array as $index => $value){
        if ($method($value, $index, $array) === true){
            return $index;
        }
    }
}

echo findIndex($data, function($arr){ 
    return $arr['userid'] == 5;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to build your own map:

```
<?php

$items = 
[
    'foo' =>
        [
            'id' => 23,
        ],
    'bar' =>
        [
            'id' => 47
        ]
];

foreach($items as $k=>$v)
    $ids_keys[$v['id']] = $k;

echo $ids_keys[47];
```

Output:

```
bar
```